# How do I exclude server information generated in the output error log

Tags: php, laravel, jenkins, laravel-5, jenkins-pipeline

**I need to exclude in the output error generated "server information and sensitive information it logs out while showing the error**

If an error Occurs it outputs a lot of **sensitive** information in the server section. how can I expect the output log of server information and  Database information?

so i need a way to hide this important data

```
Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (HY000)
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `ptcs` (`title`, `details`, `duration`, `rewards`, `ad_link`, `hit`, `type`, `count`, `membership_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values ( gxxx, Sponsored, 30, 0.100, , 20000, 1, 0, 1, 2019-12-20 03:35:36, 2019-12-20 03:35:36))
Previous exceptions
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value (HY000)
   COPY
Application frames (4)  All frames (83)
82
Illuminate\Database\QueryException 
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php664
81
PDOException 
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php458
80
PDOStatement execute
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php458
79
Illuminate\Database\Connection Illuminate\Database\{closure}
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php657
78
Illuminate\Database\Connection runQueryCallback
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php624
77
Illuminate\Database\Connection run
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php459
76
Illuminate\Database\Connection statement
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php411
75
Illuminate\Database\Connection insert
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Processors/Processor.php32
74
Illuminate\Database\Query\Processors\Processor processInsertGetId
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php2628
73
Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder insertGetId
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php1318
72
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder __call
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php823
71
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model insertAndSetId
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php788
70
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model performInsert
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php651
69
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model save
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php790
68
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\{closure}
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php1027
67
 tap
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php791
66
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder create
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/ForwardsCalls.php23
65
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model forwardCallTo
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php1608
64
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model __call
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php1620
63
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model __callStatic
…/app/Http/Controllers/AdminPTCController.php81
62
App\Http\Controllers\AdminPTCController store
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php54
61
 call_user_func_array
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php54
60
Illuminate\Routing\Controller callAction
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php45
59
Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher dispatch
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php219
58
Illuminate\Routing\Route runController
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php176
57
Illuminate\Routing\Route run
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php682
56
Illuminate\Routing\Router Illuminate\Routing\{closure}
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php30
55
Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline Illuminate\Routing\{closure}
…/app/Http/Middleware/Ban.php27
54
App\Http\Middleware\Ban handle
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php151
53
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php53
52
Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline Illuminate\Routing\{closure}
…/app/Http/Middleware/Admin.php24
51
App\Http\Middleware\Admin handle
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php151
50
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php53
49
Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline Illuminate\Routing\{closure}
…/app/Http/Middleware/StoreReferralCode.php21
48
App\Http\Middleware\StoreReferralCode handle
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php151
47
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php53
46
Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline Illuminate\Routing\{closure}
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php41
45
Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings handle
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php151
44
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php53
43
Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline Illuminate\Routing\{closure}
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php75
42
Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken handle
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php151
41
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php53
40
Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline Illuminate\Routing\{closure}
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php49
39
Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession handle
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php151
38
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php53
37
Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline Illuminate\Routing\{closure}
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php63
36
Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession handle
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php151
35
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php53
34
Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline Illuminate\Routing\{closure}
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php37
33
Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse handle
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php151
32
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php53
31
Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline Illuminate\Routing\{closure}
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php66
30
Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies handle
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php151
29
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php53
28
Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline Illuminate\Routing\{closure}
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php104
27
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline then
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php684
26
Illuminate\Routing\Router runRouteWithinStack
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php659
25
Illuminate\Routing\Router runRoute
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php625
24
Illuminate\Routing\Router dispatchToRoute
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php614
23
Illuminate\Routing\Router dispatch
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php176
22
Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php30
21
Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline Illuminate\Routing\{closure}
…/vendor/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar/src/Middleware/InjectDebugbar.php65
20
Barryvdh\Debugbar\Middleware\InjectDebugbar handle
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php151
19
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php53
18
Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline Illuminate\Routing\{closure}
…/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php57
17
Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies handle
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php151
16
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php53
15
Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline Illuminate\Routing\{closure}
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php31
14
Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest handle
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php151
13
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php53
12
Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline Illuminate\Routing\{closure}
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php31
11
Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest handle
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php151
10
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php53
9
Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline Illuminate\Routing\{closure}
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php27
8
Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize handle
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php151
7
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php53
6
Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline Illuminate\Routing\{closure}
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php62
5
Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode handle
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php151
4
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php53
3
Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline Illuminate\Routing\{closure}
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php104
2
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline then
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php151
1
Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel sendRequestThroughRouter
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php116
0
Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel handle
/home/xx/app.com/lab/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php
     * @param  array     $bindings
     * @param  \Closure  $callback
     * @return mixed
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Database\QueryException
     */
    protected function runQueryCallback($query, $bindings, Closure $callback)
    {
        // To execute the statement, we'll simply call the callback, which will actually
        // run the SQL against the PDO connection. Then we can calculate the time it
        // took to execute and log the query SQL, bindings and time in our memory.
        try {
            $result = $callback($query, $bindings);
        }

        // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
        // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
        // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
        catch (Exception $e) {
            throw new QueryException(
                $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
            );
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Log a query in the connection's query log.
     *
     * @param  string  $query
     * @param  array   $bindings
     * @param  float|null  $time
     * @return void
     */
    public function logQuery($query, $bindings, $time = null)
    {
        $this->event(new QueryExecuted($query, $bindings, $time, $this));

        if ($this->loggingQueries) {
Arguments
"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `ptcs` (`title`, `details`, `duration`, `rewards`, `ad_link` ▶"
Environment & details:
GET Data empty
POST Data
_token  
"/"
title   
" Excha"
ad_link 
""
membership_id   
"1"
rewards 
"0.100"
duration    
"30"
hit 
"20000"
status  
"1"
details 
""
Files empty
Cookies
_ga 
"GA1.2.767514765.1574096306"
__tawkuuid  
"e::::::2"
_gid    
""
__utmz  
"175573563.1575805896.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)"
__utma  
""
ref 
" ▶"
code    
" ▶"
__utmc  
"18812009"
__utmb  
"18812009.6.10.1576786660"
TawkConnectionTime  
"0"
XSRF-TOKEN  
" ▶"

" ▶"
Session empty
Server/Request Data
LSPHP_ENABLE_USER_INI   
"on"
PATH    
"/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"
TEMP    
"/tmp"
TMP 
"/tmp"
TMPDIR  
"/tmp"
PWD 
"/"
HTTP_ACCEPT 
"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8"
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING    
"gzip, deflate, br"
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE    
"en-US,en;q=0.9"
CONTENT_TYPE    
"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
CONTENT_LENGTH  
"213"
HTTP_COOKIE 
"_ga=GA1.2.767514765.1574096306; __; _gid=GA1.2.739023008.1575 ▶"
HTTP_HOST   
""
HTTP_REFERER    
""
HTTP_USER_AGENT 
"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36"
HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL  
"max-age=0"
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR    
"105.112.122.222"
HTTP_SAVE_DATA  
"on"
HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS  
"1"
HTTP_ORIGIN 
""
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO  
"https"
HTTP_X_HTTPS    
"on"
REDIRECT_HTTPS  
"on"
REDIRECT_SERVER_PORT    
"443"
REDIRECT_UNIQUE_ID  
""
REDIRECT_SCRIPT_URL 
"/admin/ptc/create"
REDIRECT_SCRIPT_URI 
""
REDIRECT_STATUS 
"200"
HTTPS   
"on"
SERVER_PORT 
"443"
UNIQUE_ID   
""
SCRIPT_URL  
""
SCRIPT_URI  
""
SERVER_SIGNATURE    
""
SERVER_SOFTWARE 
"Apache"
SERVER_NAME 
""
SERVER_ADDR 
"198.54.125.177"
REMOTE_ADDR 
"105.112.122.222"
DOCUMENT_ROOT   
""
REQUEST_SCHEME  
"https"
CONTEXT_PREFIX  
""
CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT   
""
SERVER_ADMIN    
""
SCRIPT_FILENAME 
"//"
REMOTE_PORT 
"38744"
REDIRECT_URL    
"/admin/xxx/create"
SERVER_PROTOCOL 
"HTTP/1.1"
REQUEST_METHOD  
"POST"
QUERY_STRING    
""
REQUEST_URI 
"/admin/xxx/create"
SCRIPT_NAME 
"/index.php"
PHP_SELF    
"/index.php"
REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT  
1576791336.6069
REQUEST_TIME    
1576791336
APP_NAME    
 "
APP_ENV 
"local"
APP_KEY 
""
APP_DEBUG   
"true"
APP_LOG_LEVEL   
"debug"
APP_URL 
""
CURRENCY_CODE   
""
CURRENCY_SYMBOL 
"#"
APP_SSL 
"false"
DB_CONNECTION   
"Xxxxxx"
DB_HOST 
"127.0.0.1"
DB_PORT 
"3306"
DB_DATABASE 
"Xxxxxxxxxx_xxxxx"
DB_USERNAME 
"Xxxxxxxxxx_xxxx"
DB_PASSWORD 
"Xxxxxx"
BROADCAST_DRIVER    
"log"
CACHE_DRIVER    
"file"
SESSION_DRIVER  
"file"
SESSION_LIFETIME    
"120"
QUEUE_DRIVER    
"sync"
REDIS_HOST  
"127.0.0.1"
REDIS_PASSWORD  
"null"
REDIS_PORT  
"00000"
MAIL_DRIVER 
"Xxxxx"
MAIL_HOST   
"Xxdrgughjjj.byg"
MAIL_PORT   
"465"
MAIL_USERNAME   
"Xxxxx@xxxx.ui"
MAIL_PASSWORD   
"Xxxxxxxxxx."
MAIL_ENCRYPTION 
"SSL"
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS   
"Xxxxxx@cxxxcvb.vv"
MAIL_FROM_NAME  
Xxxxxxxxxx"
MAILGUN_DOMAIN  
"Xxxxxxxxxx"
MAILGUN_SECRET  
""
RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY    
"Xxxxxxxxxx"
RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY   
"Xxxxxxxxxx"
PUSHER_APP_ID   
""
PUSHER_APP_KEY  
""
PUSHER_APP_SECRET   
""
Environment Variables
LSPHP_ENABLE_USER_INI   
"on"
PATH    
"/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"
TEMP    
"/tmp"
TMP 
"/tmp"
TMPDIR  
"/tmp"
PWD 
"/"
APP_NAME    
"Xxxxxxxxxx"
APP_ENV 
"local"
APP_KEY 
"Xxxxxxxxx"
APP_DEBUG   
"true"
APP_LOG_LEVEL   
"debug"
APP_URL 
"go.go"
CURRENCY_CODE   
""
CURRENCY_SYMBOL 
"#"
APP_SSL 
"false"
DB_CONNECTION   
"xxxxx"
DB_HOST 
"000.0.0.1"
DB_PORT 
"3306"
DB_DATABASE 
"Cccccvv_xxxx"
DB_USERNAME 
"Cccccvv_xxxx"
DB_PASSWORD 
"xxxxxx"
BROADCAST_DRIVER    
"log"
CACHE_DRIVER    
"file"
SESSION_DRIVER  
"file"
SESSION_LIFETIME    
"000"
QUEUE_DRIVER    
"sync"
REDIS_HOST  
"0000.000.000"
REDIS_PASSWORD  
"Xxxxxxxxxx"
REDIS_PORT  
"Xxxxxxxxxx"
MAIL_DRIVER 
"Xxxxxxxxxx"
MAIL_HOST   
"Xxxxxxccccxcxxxxxx.xxx"
MAIL_PORT   
"Xxx"
MAIL_USERNAME   
"Xxxxxxxxxxx@xx.xxx"
MAIL_PASSWORD   
"Xxxxxxxxxx."
MAIL_ENCRYPTION 
"SSL"
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS   
"Xxxxxx@xxxxxxx.xxx"
MAIL_FROM_NAME  
"Xxxxxxxxxxx"
MAILGUN_DOMAIN  
"Xxxxxxxxxx"
Xxxxxxccccxcxxxxxx"
RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY   
"Xxxxxxxcccccccc"
PUSHER_APP_ID   
""
PUSHER_APP_KEY  
""
PUSHER_APP_SECRET   
""
Registered Handlers
0. Whoops\Handler\PrettyPageHandler
```

Comment: I need to exclude those server information from the error output logs.

Comment: when you edit your `env` file from `APP_DEBUG=true` to `APP_DEBUG=false` it will hide all errors

Comment: Thanks a lot. Let me try that now.

Comment: Thanks, it fixed it.

Comment: accept the answer if it really helped you

Answer (score 1):

if you still need `debug` to be enabled, but need to keep safe your data (or in case you forget to turn it off on production):

In `config/app.php` add `array` of `debug_blacklist`:

```php
'debug_blacklist' => [
    '_ENV' => [ //Data from .evn file
        'APP_KEY',
        'APP_URL',
        ... //any other
    ],
    '_SERVER' => [ //data from server variables
        'SERVER_ADDR',
        'SERVER_PORT',
        ... //any other
    ],
    '_POST' => [ //data from `POST`
        'password',
        ... //any other
    ],
]
```

> From [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/configuration#hiding-environment-variables-from-debug)

Answer (score 0):

In laravel framework there is an option called `APP_DEBUG` that it is by default set
to `true` that is mean that any error will be shown to fix it but when you start to deploy 
you app to a server it is important to change this option to `false` it this moment all error will be saved in your `storage` folder as logs that no user can see it

so all you need is to change your `APP_DEBUG` to `false` from `env` file

```
APP_DEBUG=false
```

you can read more about errors in laravel [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/errors#configuration)

Comment: I just did but it wasn't adding up. Let me try again. It says I have less than 15 point but it's recorded